# Finding group from it's presentation

Tags: group-theory

I have a group presentation $G = <x,y : xy=yx, x^5 = y^3>$ and I'm trying to find what this group looks like.

I think the first relation allows me to write each element of $G$ as $x^a y^b$. So if I take a surjective homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z}^2 \to G$ given by $\phi((a,b)) = x^ay^b$ then it seems that the kernel of this map is any element of the form $(5k,3k)$ i.e $\mathbb{Z}$. This would then tell me by the first isomorphism theorem $G =\mathbb{Z}$, which doesn't seem quite right!

Comment: Thanks, have now edited the question

Comment: The correct statement is that $\mathbb{Z}^{2}/{\rm ker \phi} \cong {\rm Im} \phi.$

Comment: Is this not the statement I am making? Because $\phi$ is onto and I've shown the kernel of $\phi$ is $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: The kernel of $\phi$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}.$ But strictly speaking, you need to justify that $\mathbb{Z}^{2}/ {\rm ker} \phi$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z},$ which the solution below does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe $(x^ay^b)^5=x^{5a}y^{5b}=y^{3a+5b}$ and $(x^ay^b)^3=x^{3a}y^{3b}=x^{3a+5b}$. If we can solve $3a+5b=1$ then the element $x^ay^b$ will generate all of $G$. It is not hard to solve in this instance by hand.

Comment: Thanks, so $x^2 y^{-1}$ generates the whole group and so it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$